# How to remove IIS 6 Management Compatibility?

Tags: windows-7, iis-7

I am using Windows 7 for testing one Windows Server program that requires IIS to be installed on my machine. Problems arise when I enabled IIS on my machine with the *Turn Windows features on or off* feature of Windows 7. I realized that now I have two IIS Managers on start menu search; a version without number and a version labeled 6.0.

Now, my problem is that only the version without specific number is working, while the 6.0 version is showing nothing. My installation process accidentally takes the non working one.

A fix would be to remove one of these installations. How to do that if the only option in the UI is to switch that feature on or off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not "parallel installation" -- you have **IIS v7.5 ONLY**.

Those "v6" are for compatibility reasons (for software that configures/interacts with IIS programatically but is old or unaware of IIS v7. You can remove IIS v6 support via "Turn Windows features on or off" if you do not need it:

1. Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off
2. Internet Information Services -> Web management Tools -> **IIS 6 Management Compatibility**.